# Dynamic file download buttons in VB .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download

I have a page in a VB NET 2005 web project. On page load, it takes data from the logged in user, looks up a set of documents owned by that user, and creates a "download" button for each. Currently, this button opens a new window that streams the document, but we'd like the button itself to trigger a download.

I've got some options for this, but they all seem kind of hacky, and while I haven't found any good solutions, this seems like it should be a solved problem.

The buttons are in a form (so postback with hidden fields is one of the "hacky" options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have a GridView with 3 columns: `Filename`, `Size` and a `Download` button. Then set the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` of the button. For security reason, it might be a better idea to use the user's document id instead of the full path name like I did. You can get the real file using combination of current user and the document id.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Filename">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFilename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Filename") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSize" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Size") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download"
            CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the class which I use to hold the list of files for download. A list of this class binds to the GridView.

```
Public Class MyFileInfo
    Public Property Filename As String
    Public Property Fullname As String
    Public Property Size As Long
End Class
```

Last is handling the Download button click. I use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` to pass what button is click and what file it needs to give to the browser. I use stream and write to the browser with proper `MIME type` in the header.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Download" Then
        DownloadFile(e.CommandArgument)
    End If
End Sub

Sub DownloadFile(filename As String)
    Using fs = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
        Response.BufferOutput = False
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fs.Length.ToString())
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Path.GetFileName(filename))
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword"

        fs.Position = 0
        fs.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Full code (aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Filename">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFilename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Filename") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSize" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Size") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download"
                                CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Full code (code behind):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then BindGridList()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
        If e.CommandName = "Download" Then
            DownloadFile(e.CommandArgument)
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub BindGridList()
        GridView1.DataSource = GetFiles()
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Function GetFiles() As List(Of MyFileInfo)
        Dim listFileInfos = New List(Of MyFileInfo)

        Dim dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Data"))
        Dim fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc")
        For Each fileInfo In fileInfos
            listFileInfos.Add(New MyFileInfo With {.Filename = fileInfo.Name, .Size = fileInfo.Length, .Fullname = fileInfo.FullName})
        Next

        Return listFileInfos
    End Function

    Sub DownloadFile(filename As String)
        Using fs = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
            Response.BufferOutput = False
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fs.Length.ToString())
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Path.GetFileName(filename))
            Response.ContentType = "application/msword"

            fs.Position = 0
            fs.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyFileInfo
    Public Property Filename As String
    Public Property Fullname As String
    Public Property Size As Long
End Class
```

Comment: Perfect, and thank you for the response. I feel kind of silly for not thinking about databinding the records, rather than fetching the records after the button is pressed (which is the current implementation). And yeah, we're using a Guid as a File ID, though there ARE plenty of questionable design decisions in this...thing I've inherited.